# Equation connected by lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, amsmath, package-writing

I have written a code that defines a new environment in which aligned equation are connected by lines as in the image:

[image]

I think it is useful when, inside the align environment, there is the need of splitting on step in more than one line like in this second example:

[image]

It uses `tikz` and `amsmath` packages. Lines can connect also different math sign than `=` and the line width is customizable.

My questions are:

1. I initially wrote this code for learning but then I search for packages that already include this feature and I didn't find anything. Do you know if there exist such a package?
2. Do you think it is a useful feature? How can I improve it?
3. If the answer to second point is "yes", do you think it's better to write a package with this feature or to suggest its insertion into the `amsmath` package?

**EDIT**

The `\vdotswithin` feature provided by the `mathtools` is different because it adds the `vdots` in a separated line:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{align*}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) &= \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) + \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) \\
&\vdotswithin{=}\\
&= \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: 2. Lighter, shorter, … customization. 3. This is not going to be inserted in `amsmath`. — In your second example you are not using `align` correctly. The `split` environment should be used or at least the `\nonumber`/`\notag` macro. (The equation number `5`, `6` and `7` are used in the same “equation line”.) — For aligned signs I don’t see the point of the vertical lines (they are already aligned).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, I missed a `\nonumber`, you're right. Maybe I'm the only that doing calculations by hand uses lines to keep things more understandable, I don't know. I'm asking here to know if it is a feature that can be useful for someone or if it is useful only for me (so no need to create a package) :-)

Comment: Nice. Maybe it could be added to `mathtools`? The latter has `\vdotswithin`, which can be used to put `vdots` between `=` signs or elsewhere.

Comment: Nice catch by @Alex. You can then change the `vdots` to `rule`

Comment: If there are multiple alignment points, can the multiple alignment symbols be joined? Can one replace the rule with something else (a dashed line, a dotted line, a decorated line)? (I imagine the answer to the second question to be affirmative, since TikZ is being used?)

Comment: @Alex I will check this feature of `mathtools`. If it is so similar to mine then I think there is no need of writing a package (also because my code is probably much more complicated and full of bugs than the `\vdotswithin` one) but I can suggest of adding something like a `\rulewithin` feature.

Comment: @Alex I checked the feature of the `mathtools` package you suggested. It is different from mine because in that case the `vdots` are inserted in a new line and they can not span more than one line, I will add an example in my question to be more clear.

Comment: @red And what about `\shortvdotswithin`? Anyway, I think `mathtools` would be a good place for your code.

Comment: How come I didn't see this before? While I write something like this on the blackboard, I would never use it in a printed document: it's easy to lose one's tracks on a wide board, not on a finely printed document.

Comment: I agree with egreg's comment.  As for including in `amsmath` or `mathtools` the fact that you use `tikz` would add a lot of overhead to those packages.  My opinion is that you are best writing a separate style file for this.  Isn't this question mostly opinion?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what answers you are expecting here. It seems you are asking for comments. Would you accept an answer "As far as I know, no such package exists"?

Comment: What exactly is the bounty attached to this question meant to be *for*? What sort of attention is required? That is, it looks as though comments have more-or-less answered the 3 queries: 1. Probably not but `\shortvdotswithin` may be similar. 2. Possibly not to others but if you find it useful, somebody else may. If this is often used in writing on paper, it might be useful to show students how to keep track in that context. Various suggestions were made but there's no code here to improve. 3. `mathtools` or separate. Probably separate given `tikz`. What further is expected exactly?

Comment: I am not the person who open the bounty... Maybe this person is suggesting me to create the packet?

Comment: @Red I know you're not and I have no idea if that's the suggestion or not. That's sort of my point: it is entirely unclear what is expected which would count as answering the question and go beyond the comments. (Can you get a bounty for an answer to your own question?)

Comment: Hi, You received some good answers. Is one of them answering your question If yes, please accept it by clicking on the tick mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) & \rnode{A}{\;=\;} \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)+\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) \\
                           & \rnode{B}{\;=\;} \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)\\
                           & \rnode{C}{\;=\;} mx+b\\
                           & \rnode{D}{\;=\;} Ax + By + C
\end{align*}
\psset{nodesepB=2pt}\ncline{A}{B}\ncline{B}{C}\ncline{C}{D}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

From the question, without code given, it is difficult to tell how easy/difficult the OP's current implementation is.  So I put this forward, realizing that it may be step backward.  If so, please advise, and I will remove the answer.

REVISED ANSWER:

Here, I create three macros `\topeq`, `\mideq`, and `\boteq`, each with one optional argument.  The first extends a short vertical bar downward from the equal sign, as if were the top equation in the list; the second extends a short bar upward and downward; the third extends a bar upward, as if it were the last equation on the list.  For textstyle equations, this should be sufficient to solve the problem.  However, if the equations extend vertically in display style, the bars will be too short as shown below:

[image]

For this reason, the optional argument to each of these macros is a length to make one of the bars (for `\topeq`, it is the bar length below the `=`, for `\mideq` and `\boteq`, it is the length to extend above the `=`).

THE ADVANTAGE TO THIS APPROACH over my original solution is that one does not need the exact length of the vertical bar, rather one only needs to make it long enough to overlay the adjacent bar.  Thus, the optional argument length typically has to only be accurate to, let's say, `1ex`.  The other advantage, as already mentioned, is that for textstyle equations, no optional arguments should be needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\topeq[1][1ex]{%
  \mathrel{\stackunder[0pt]{=}{\smash{\rule[-#1]{.5pt}{#1}}}}%
}
\newcommand\boteq[1][1.5ex]{%
  \mathrel{\stackon[1.6pt]{=}{\smash{\rule{.5pt}{#1}}}}%
}
\newcommand\mideq[1][1.5ex]{%
  \mathrel{\stackon[1.6pt]{%
    \stackunder[0pt]{=}{\smash{\rule[-1ex]{.5pt}{1ex}}}%
  }{\smash{\rule{.5pt}{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) &\topeq \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) + \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) \\
&\mideq[5ex] \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)\\
&\mideq[4ex] mx+b\\
&\boteq Ax + By + C
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This same result, with the extensions is shown here:

[image]

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

In this MWE, I implement `\coneq` (connect equal sign) which draws a vertical bar upward from an equal sign.  The downside is that the user must specify how long the vertical bar is.  The upside is the implementation is trivial.  (I have a slightly revised notion that I am working on, and will post, if successful).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\coneq#1{\mathrel{\stackon[2pt]{=}{\smash{\rule{.5pt}{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) &= \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) + \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1) \\
&\coneq{5.1ex} \prod_{z^n=-1}(w_1(z)^n+1)\\
&\coneq{4.5ex} mx+b\\
&\coneq{2.0ex} Ax + By + C
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]